# ReSharper 8 - Live Template Macros - HotspotItems

Tags: macros, resharper

I am currently using ReSharper V8.1. I've only recently began using ReSharper and have found some interest in their LiveTemplate Macros. I've conjured up a solution to return a list of HotspotItems from a constant, similar to ReSharper's predefined macro "Comma-delimited list of values". In the method I take the constant variable of the template parameter and do a split string on them to provide a collection of HotSpotItems. Unfortunately it doesn't work if I use the macro more than one time within a template. Below is an extreme hack job showing my implementation of the method HotspotItems of IMacroImplementation.

I am hoping that someone out there may have done some work in this area and could possibly provide an example of how they've implemented IMacroImplementation which provides a list of items from a constant and also allows for multiple uses within a single template. 
Thank you.

```
    public override HotspotItems GetLookupItems(IHotspotContext context)
    {



        HotspotItems hotSpotItems = null;
        foreach (var hotspot in context.HotspotSession.Hotspots)
        {
            if (hotspot.Expression != null && ((MacroCallExpressionNew)hotspot.Expression).Definition is Macros.DisplayMultipleItems)
            {
                //hotspot.CurrentValue
                var multiItems = ((MacroCallExpressionNew) hotspot.Expression).Definition as DisplayMultipleItems;
                if (!multiItems.ItemSet)
                {

                    var expression = hotspot.Expression as MacroCallExpressionNew;
                    IMacroParameterValueNew baseValue = expression.Parameters[0].GetValue(context.SessionContext.Solution.GetLifetime(), context.HotspotSession);
                    string templateValue = baseValue.GetValue();
                    multiItems.ItemSet = true;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateValue) && templateValue.Split(',').Any())
                    {
                        var lookupItems = templateValue.Split(',').Select(param => new TextLookupItem(param)).Cast<ILookupItem>().ToList();
                        if (hotSpotItems == null)
                            hotSpotItems = new HotspotItems(lookupItems);
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var item in lookupItems)
                            {
                              hotSpotItems.Items.Add(item);        
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return hotSpotItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fire up dotPeek and point it to the ReSharper bin directory and take a look at `ListMacroDef` and `ListMacroImpl`, which is the implementation for the comma-delimited list macro.

The definition derives from `SimpleMacroDefinition`. It gets given the parameters in the call to `GetPlaceholder`, looks at the first and splits it by comma, returning the first item as the placeholder.

`ListMacroImpl` is just as simple. Its constructor has an `[Optional]` parameter of type `MacroParameterValueCollection`. This is the list of parameter values specified in the hotspot editor. You'll want to check for null and take the first parameter, which will be your delimited list. It then overrides `GetLookupItems` and returns `HotspotItems.Empty` if the parameter value is null, or parses the value and returns a list of `TextLookupItem`.

You don't need to look at the session and list of hotspots - that will get you all hotspots in the session, when you're only interested in the current hotspot, and ReSharper will create a new `IMacroImplementation` for each hotspot and give you those values in your constructor.